Third-party cookie will be blocked - warning, not able to logout
I want to remove the warning and be able to logout
https://link-bee-roan.vercel.app/ this is the link
I am setting cookies here
 res.cookie('token', token, {
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: 'none', 
    });

My cors
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://link-bee-roan.vercel.app",
    credentials: true
}));

In the frontEnd
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
.
.
.
let response = await axios.post("https://linkbee-2.onrender.com/login", {
      // let response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        userID, password
   },{ 
   withCredentials: true,
});

I am getting the third party cookie error in the console,
However I am able to see the cookie, but  when I click the logout button, the cookie is not getting deleted,
This is the logout backend code,
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    console.log("this is the cookie :: " ,  req.cookies.token);
    res.clearCookie('token').send(req.cookies.token);
});

This is the related function in the front end
const handleLogout = async (e) => {
        try {
            let response = await axios.post(`${backendLink}/user/logout`);
            console.log("this is the respose :: " , response);
            // window.location.href = "/";
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("error :: ", error);
        }
    }

Getting the cookie, but the cookie is not getting deleted even after the logout code above;


There is not enough context in your question. For example, you speak of "the extension" but do not explain what that is. At any rate, https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd may be relevant.

There is an extension called "Cookie-Editor" where I can see the cookies stored, as I am getting the warning I am not able to see the cookie, and not able to remove as well, so that i can log out

You don’t need an extension for that, you can already inspect everything stored in the Storage tab of the dev tools.

And that 3rd party cookie warning has nothing immediately to do with your issue, it’s a general warning.

I am just using the extension for ease, how can I remove the warning? are my cookie attributes right for production?

https://link-bee-roan.vercel.app is not an acceptable value for the Domain attribute.

Even after remove that the warning persists

Where this "Hi" in the response header comes from? Cookies are delivered to the front in the header called "set-cookie".  You need to localise the problem whether the cookies are not sent from the back, or are not parsed on the front. For that - open the network tab before running let response = await axios.post( request, and check what is being sent on the wire. If the set-cookie header is there, the problem is on the front. If it is not there - it's back not sending them. As deceze said - the warning and "can't see cookies" are 2 separate issues.

Please check the edits, the cookie is not getting deleted after I click the logout button

From the documentation:

Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge.

Having
 res.cookie('token', token, {
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: 'none', 
    });

to set cookies, you should have
  res.clearCookie('token', {
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: 'none', 
    }).send();

to mirror the options.
Saying that, cookies are stored on the client, and in your particular case (no serverside logic in router.post('/logout' handler, the cookie is not "http only", no other cookies) you can delete it (and effectively logout) straight in the browser, saving on the HTTP request:
document.cookie = 'token; Max-Age=0 path=/; domain=...etc' 

